# modelling question regarding smooth depressions on surfaces

Tags: modeling

im fairly new to modelling in blender and im working on modelling a watch I designed. I want it to have two smooth depressions as shown in the attached sketch, however I do not know how to get to this point. I have already made the polygon frame of the desired shape to be cut.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this.
The most basic is using smaller and smaller loops (*inset faces tool* is your friend)
Subdivision modifier will then smooth it out.

Two examples:
[image: Example using only loops and subsurf modifier]

Other (more elegant) ways may include *Boolean modifier*, *edge creases*, *sculpting*, etc.
Note: It was fun to try this, if you need any help, let me know.

Comment: thank you for answering my question so quickly , insetting the faces really did help, however I cant seem to get the same smooth effect you have gotten in the attached picture. Once I inset the faces and taper them downward and exit x ray mode I can no longer see them.

Comment: 1) Try disabling *Subdivision* modifier in edit mode (the third icon).
It sometimes hides underlaying geometry.

2) In my example there’s a *Mirror* modifier applied.
Only left part is editable geometry, right part is mirrored.

Hope this helps.